# How can we translate this sentence into chinese?

Tags: translation

Can you tell me the structure and grammar of the sentence?

> In the main new effort presented inthis paper, an approach is developed for integrating
>   the PSO algorithm as a driver at both the top and the discipline levels of a multidisciplinary design optimization (MDO) framework which is based on the Target Cascading (TC) method.

Comment: I don't see any prior effort from you to translate this. Besides, your question title is misleading as it has nothing to do with the content of the question. Even the sentence "Can you tell me the structure and grammar of the sentence?" is vague. Do you want to know the structure and grammar of passage you quoted in ENGLISH or CHINESE? On top of that, we are not a translation service as per [faq]. This is simply a bad question all around. Voted to close and voted down.

Answer (score 3):

You know, this is not a forum for providing translation services. So I will just analyze the sentence structure for you.

In the main new effort presented in this paper -- 地点状语

an approach -- 主语

is developed -- 谓语

for integrating the PSO algorithm as a driver at both the top and the discipline levels of a multidisciplinary design optimization (MDO) framework -- 目的状语

which is based on the Target Cascading (TC) method -- 定语从句